# Is it possible for a batch file to create a file, but only if the file isn't already there?

Tags: file, batch-file

I would like to know if its possible for a batch file to create a file in a certain location, but only if it doesn't exist there.

For example, if the file in question doesn't exist, create it. Otherwise, do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use "if":

```
if not exist c:\test\test.txt type NUL > c:\test\test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 2>> c:\test\test.txt
```

If echo ever writes anything to the error stream you'll get a shock, but I can't think of any circumstance where it would...

Answer (score 1):

```
if not exist C:\test\test.txt copy NUL C:\test\test.txt
```

(And it's really hard typing those paths. I think I never touched anything below the drive root for a few years by now. Are you creating files on Unix systems in `/` out of habit too?)

Answer (score 0):

if not exist C:\test\test.txt echo (what you want to be inside of the file here) >>C:\test\test.txt

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to create a file with a batch file:

```
if not exist "C:\folder\test file.txt" goto create
exit
:create
echo Your>"C:\folder\test file.txt"
echo Text>>"C:\folder\test file.txt"
echo Here>>"C:\folder\test file.txt"
```

If you want you can replace `exit` with code for handling the existing file.

If the file exists, nothing will happen.
If the file doesn't exist, a file will be created with the text:

```
Your
Text
Here
```

It works. I tested it.

Comment: May I ask why this got a down vote? This appears to be the best answer in this conversation.